# useCallback dependencies for array of items

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

I have a list of cards. When I add them to favourites by pressing a button, it changes the color of that button.
However, I just want that particular card to re-render after adding to favourites.

```
const addFavouriteHandler = useCallback((id: number) => {
   dispatch(addFav(id));
}, [ ?? ])

// This is my card in the list
<MovieCard
   key={movie.id}
   movie={movie}
   addFavourite={addFavouriteHandler}
   removeFavourite={removeFavouriteHandler}
   isFavourite={isFavourite}
/>
```

What would be the dependencies of the useCallback here?

Comment: Could you provide more context to this?

Comment: I think Giovani has the answer below, but you should ***highly*** consider adding the [React hooks eslint plugin](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin) to your project as it will flag this and inform you what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you got a warning on missing dependency for `dispatch` function, so your `useCallback` would be:

```
const addFavouriteHandler = useCallback((id: number) => {
   dispatch(addFav(id));
}, [dispatch]);
```

The real problem is that I don't think you need a custom hook in this case, just write:

```
const addFavouriteHandler = (id: number) => {
   dispatch(addFav(id));
};
```

Then, if you want to render `MovieCard` after you added it to favourites, if `isFavourite` is something like:

```
isFavourite = arrayOfFavourites.includes(movie.id)
```

where `arrayOfFavourites` is the array filled by `dispatch(addFav(id));`, then your `MovieCard` will be for sure re-rendered because now card id is on `arrayOfFavourites`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, but is there a way to re-render only that card from where the `onClick` was triggered?

Comment: @LokeshBajracharya its just necessary to connect the `MovieCard` state to something that will change when you add the card to favourites. I think in `MovieCard` you have something on html that is connected to `isFavourite` prop (an icon on card that means that card is a favourite card). In this case, card will be re-rendered. Is my assumption on  `MovieCard` wrong?